# Pycharm 2023.2.5 professional not recognizing previously-created Projects by pycharm 2019.3 professional

Tags: pycharm, project, upgrade, missing-data, previous-installation

I was running Pycharm 2019.3.3 and running a bunch of projects.
I had to upgrade to 2023.2.5 and now Pycharm is not recognizing any of my previously created projects.

I opened pycharm, and instead of seeing previous projects, saw nothing.  I need to have projects that include a combination of html, python and css files.  not sure how to get the new pycharm to point to the old files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The solution is opening the project manually inside PyCharm. Inside the IDE in the top-left corner go to `File` `>` `Open` and select the project's directory. The structure of the project is kept in the `.idea` folder inside the project folder, so it hasn't changed you just need to reopen it.